# Finding number of groups created with CollectionViewSource grouping

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, collectionviewsource

I am having a list of messages and I am grouping them based on server(serverId) each message belongs to, like this -

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="MessageTypesByServer"
                      Source="{Binding MessageTypes, Mode=OneWay}">
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="ServerId" />
    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

and using a `Group Style` to display each group in a `GroupBox` like this -

```
<GroupBox Margin="0,0,0,3"
          Header="{Binding Name}">
   <ItemsPresenter />
</GroupBox>
```

Now, if the messages are from single server then I don't want to display the serverId in header of `GroupBox`, for doing this I need to find out the number of groups which are there in `CollectionViewSource`;

How can I do this in XAML? (I know I can find this is in my VM and hide/show header based on a property in VM etc. but I would like to do this in XAML).

**Update:**

I tried to use the CollectionViewSource.View like this -

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}" />

    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding View.Groups.Count, Source={StaticResource MessageTypesByServer}}"
                     Value="1">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="No Server Name" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

but this doesn't work, View is always null(when seen in Snoop).

**Update 2**

I was able to get it working with a converter like this -

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=., Source={StaticResource MessageTypesByServer},  
    Converter={ValueConverters:CollectionViewSourceToGroupCountConverter}}"
             Value="1">
    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{x:Static System:String.Empty}" />
</DataTrigger>
```

and the converter logic -

```
ICollectionView view = value as ICollectionView;
if (view != null)
{
    return view.Groups.Count;
}

return 0;
```

although it is fine, I will be happy if I can do this without converter! Anyone having idea why the code in 1'st update doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

You can bind to the `CollectionViewSource` and access the `View.Groups` property, which is an [observable collection of groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.groups.aspx) -- `cvs.View.Groups.Count` is what you are after.

Do keep in mind that even when there is just one server involved the user should be able to somehow identify *which* one.

Comment: thanks, I was not able to find this; yes you are right but in my scenario server is a very technical detail and all clients won't need that, only few having multiple server need to know the server specific details.